# Summation of $S = -2+4-6+8-10+12+\cdots + 52$

Tags: solution-verification, summation

> How can we evaluate the following summation?
>
> $$S_{-} = -2+4-6+8-10+12+\cdots + 52$$

Each couple of terms, such as $(-2)$ and $4$, will sum up to $2$, and so knowing the number of such couples $n$, we can say that

$$S_{-} = 2n$$

However, how can we find the $n$? Which I think we can do by treating the summation as

$$S_{+} = 2+4+6+8+10+12+\cdots + 52$$

Whose number of terms can then be calculated as $\frac{52-2}{2}+1 = 26$. But recalling that we coupled each two terms starting from $2$, there should be $13$ terms in summation. Thus,

$$S_{-} = 13\times 2 = 26$$

Is this a meaningful approach?

Comment: its slightly overthought but its correct. The easier way is seeing that 4(2x2) is the second term, 8(2x4) is the fourth, 12(2x6) the sixth and so on so 52(2x26) is the 26th term so ur sum is 26 (since each 2 term gives 2 as sum)

Comment: You can rewrite your sum as two sums, one with the negative and one with the positive. Then you factor the sums and you would get the result. $S=-2(1+3+5...) + 4(1+2+3+...)$

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback!

Comment: Why not just count how many numbers there are? And then just divide by 2 to get $n$